How to get URL of the current active window (linux ubuntu)
Using the x-win library which gives me the app name, title, icon and URL.
But URL is only available for windows and macos.
In Ubuntu (x11), have tried tools like xprop, xdotool and xwininfo but none of them give me the URL if the current active window is a browser.
Is there a way i can get the URL of the active window.

There is no such thing as window URL for X11.

what about wayland ?

No idea about Wayland but my guess would be no. What's a window URL anyway?

The x-win library does not support URL for linux. In the documentation, it has a subsection titled: "URLs (Only available for Darwin and Windows Systems)
It is possible to get URL of browsers window for macOS and Windows."

@n.m.couldbeanAI If my active window is a browser, then I want to get the URL the user is on.

@RakinRkz I know it isn't available that's why I asked is there any other way we can get the URL on linux.

Have you looked at this question and answer? Get URL of currently active chromium or chrome tab from external process

X11 has no idea what a browser is. It draws shapes on the screen, that's all.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
